Blazor breakpoints become disabled with Visual Studio
Once again breakpoints become disabled when debugging Blazor app with Visual Studio.
Last time I solved it in a roundabout way, by cloning app in different computer with a fresh version of Visual Studio and after problem was resolved brought it back to main computer.
Problem has appeared again, but this time I have a clue: Checking Debug > Windows > Modules shows Client dll is not loaded. Have found several suggestions in Stackoverflow.com and tried to implement them but still have not been able to solve problem.
TIA
